# Can not access nginx container on a local windows machine

Tags: nginx, docker

I'm running an nginx container on a windows 10 machine. I've stripped it down to a bare minimum - an nginx image provided in the Docker hub. I'm running it using:

`docker run --name ng -d -P nginx`

This is the output of `docker ps`:

`b5411ff47ca6        nginx               "nginx -g 'daemon off"   22 seconds ago      Up 21 seconds       0.0.0.0:32771->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32770->443/tcp   ng`

And this is the IP I'm getting when doing `docker inspect ng`: "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2"

So, the next thing I'm trying to do is access the Nginx server from the host machine by opening `http://172.17.0.2:32771` in browser of the host machine. This is not working (host not found etc).

Please advise

Answer (score 34, accepted):

On windows, you are using Docker Toolbox, and the IP you need is `192.168.99.100` (which is the IP of the Docker Toolbox VM). The IP you got is the IP of the container **inside** the VM, which is not accessible directly from Windows.

Comment: Magic http://i.imgur.com/gBKH3cj.gif
This is the case on Windows only though, right? If I deploy it on a Linux machine it will work as expected?

Comment: Both Windows and OS X. On linux, you will be able to access it directly using `172.17.0.2:80` (using the IP address of the container directly) or `localhost:32771` (using the IP address of the host AND the mapped port). `-P` maps the container port to a random host port. You can also use `-p host_port:container_port` to map to a specified port.

Comment: Furthermore, you can also directly access the container without port mapping on Linux, and that is more secure if you don't need to access it outside the linux box.

Answer (score 5):

1. Follow this article... https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/#run-the-app
2. And make sure your application is running not just docker.

> docker run -d -p 4000:80 friendlyhello

After this on Windows 10 host machine

1. Worked http://192.168.99.100:4000/
2. Not working: http://localhost:4000/

Comment: best and most helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following command to map the internal port 80 on the running container to port 82 off localhost:

docker run --name webserver2 -d -p 82:80 nginx

accessing nginx image off localhost:82 works great.

The port you want to access from your local web browser is the first number before the :80 which is where nginx image runs virtually in the container.

There is lots of miscommunication out there on the issue -- it's a simple port mapping between the host machine (Windows you are running) and the container running on docker.